# Angle of Rotation

Tags: javascript, math

Here is the code, I am trying to get the angle of rotation. I am rotating an image around a dial. I am getting all the angles right except when it reaches 270 degree it does some funky stuff. The angle changes to negative. It works fine from 0 to 270 but i cant get it to display angle between 270 to 360..Please give me some suggestions

```
    this.rotate = function(x){
    this.node.style.MozTransform="rotate("+x+"deg)";
    this.node.style.WebkitTransform="rotate("+x+"deg)";
    this.node.style.OTransform="rotate("+x+"deg)";
    this.node.style.msTransform="rotate("+x+"deg)";
    this.node.style.Transform="rotate("+x+"deg)";

myintID = setInterval(function(){
    //Math!
    angleFromEye = Math.atan2((cursorLocation.y-self.my_y), cursorLocation.x-  self.my_x)*(180/Math.PI)+ 90;
    //Rotate
    self.rotate(angleFromEye);
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be that the problem is going to be with the `.rotate` function, which you didn't show us. Did you mean to paste more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the angle is negative for the values -90 to 0 also, but you add 90 to the angle, so you don't see that.

Simply add 360 to the angle when it's negative:

```
if (angleFromEye < 0) angleFromEye += 360;
```

Comment: This is not working. I am trying to get the angle of rotation.. It works perfectly fine until 270. But then its gives me random negative number...

Comment: @subL: No, the negative numbers are not random at all, they are simply negative angles. The angle -45 is the same as 315, i.e. 360-45.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your conversion from the range of return values of `atan2` to your desired range.

`atan2` gives angles in radians, in the range `[-pi,pi]`, you want angles in degrees in the range `[0,360]`.

Your conversion gives you angles in degrees in the range `[-180+90,180+90] = [-90,270]`.

```
atan2(...)*(180/Math.PI) + 90
```

Try this instead:

```
atan2(...)*(180/Math.PI) + 180
```

Comment: It works but when i rotate the image now.. 0 is in 270's position ..While my dial have numbers 0-9 and i want 0 = 0degree instead of 90..

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a jQuery plugin, that allows you to get the rotation of an element, and also to rotate an element. It works in ie7 and ie8 as well.
Here: http://wp-dreams.com/jquery-element-rotation-plugin/